# display galleria list of images in random order

Tags: jquery, galleria

I was wondering if it's possible to randomise the list of images galleria uses to be different each time on document.load

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this would be to do it on the server with the scripting language of your choice. If you want to do something like this on the client side, you could look at this plugin [here](http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/shuffle/demo.html), which allows you to randomize an array of jQuery objects.

Should be as easy as:

```
$('.images').shuffle().galleria();
```

Comment: Thanks so much I had that plugin yesterday and couldn't get it to work, was clearly missing the important code you added, GREAT!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Put the images in an array, sort the [array randomly](http://javascript.about.com/library/blsort2.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Just use galleria's option

```
dataSort: 'random'
```

would do the job without accommodating other solution